# Pronunciation of (King) Leir in Early Modern English

Tags: pronunciation, early-modern-english

Shakespeare's *King Lear* may have used the anonymous play [*King Leir*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_Leir) as a source. Lear is pronounced /lɪə<sup>r</sup>/ in present-day English and I assume that Early Modern English used essentially the same pronunciation.

But I am not sure about the pronunciation of Leir. Do we have enough knowledge about Early Modern English pronunciation to know how the name was most likely pronounced? Was it pronounced the same as Lear? Or did it rhyme with lair (/leə<sup>r</sup>/ in present-day English)? Or perhaps even  /leɪ<sup>r</sup>/?

Comment: Should the King's name have just one syllable? Aren't all your pronunciations disyllabic? Are you thinking of *layer*?

Comment: It's going to be tough to pin down — the *OED* indicates that the spellings "leir", "lair", "lear", "leer", "lere", "layer" etc. were pretty much interchangeable in the 1500s and 1600s.

Comment: You could be correct and I would always query any  assumption that Early Modern English used 'essentially the same pronunciation' we hear today.